# ERROR:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, arraylist, tablemodel

Am trying to design a calendar using a j table, table model which uses and array list and the Gregorian calendar. i implemented the  setValueAt() in the table model that i use to draw the calendar. but when i run the programme, i get the message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
```

Can any one help me to fix this error?

```
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
    nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    //Draw calendar
    for (int i=1; i<=nod; i++){
        int row = (i+som-2)/7;
        int column  =  (i+som-2)%7;
        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt( i, row, column);

    }
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue,  int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    data1.get(rowIndex).set(columnIndex, aValue.toString());
}
```

**Update**

I initialized `data1` by passing a two dimensional arraylist argument to constructor of the tablemodel.

```
ArrayList <String> column1 = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data1 = new ArrayList(); 
public mymodel(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> d, ArrayList<String> c) { 
    this.column1 = c; 
    this.data1 = d;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the line where  you initialise `data1` please?

Comment: i initialized data1 by passing a two dimensional arraylist argument to constructor of the tablemodel.                   ArrayList <String> column1 = new ArrayList();
   
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data1 = new ArrayList();
     
   public mymodel(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> d, ArrayList<String> c){
       this.column1 = c;
       this.data1= d;    
   }

Comment: So what value are you passing in as `d`?  Whatever it is, it looks like it doesn't have enough rows and columns pre-made in it, for your later call to `setValueAt`.

Comment: Thanks David for your quick response, first and foremost, i built this model to act as a blue print for ant table that can arrange it's data in an arraylist. THE CASE I HAVE HOWEVER IS ONE OF INSERTING VALUES TO THE TABLE AT SPECIFIC CELLS AS SHOWN IN THE CODE. THE CELLS MAY NOT NECESSARIRY START FROM INDEX ONE BECUASE IT GENRATES THE SPECFIC INDEX FROM THE VALUE OF DAY OF WEEK AND NUMBER OF MONTH FROM THE GREGORIAN CALANDER CLASS. DO I HAVE TO PASS TO THE MODEL THE ARGUMENT OR I CAN INSERT THOSE SPECIFIC VALUES IN THE CELLS?

Comment: The expression `data1.get(rowIndex)` will always throw an exception if the row doesn't exist.  So will `set(columnIndex, value)`.  Therefore, you need to make sure your lists are all large enough first.  So instead of starting `data1` with an empty `ArrayList`, you should start it out with an `ArrayList` full of enough `ArrayList` objects for the number of rows you have, and each `ArrayList` inside needs to have enough entries for the number of columns you have.

Comment: David, you are smart!! It really worked perfectly: // data = new ArrayList();
 (int i=0; i<6; i++){ data2 = new ArrayList();for (int j=0; j<7; j++){data2.add(j, null);
 } data.add(i, data2); } 
The challellange now is that this calender will be used by more than 14 JFrames of which it has to insert the date in the textfield after the user has selected the date on the calender. is there any way i can determine which frame is active or i have to implement it for each frame.

Comment: That sounds like something that should be posted as a separate question.